# Searching through a hash in ruby with values that are methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problem searching through a hash where my values are methods.  I just wan't to run the method where `plan_type` matches the key.

```
def method(plan_type, plan, user)
  {
    foo: plan_is_foo(plan, user),
    bar: plan_is_bar(plan, user),
    waa: plan_is_waa(plan, user),
    har: plan_is_har(user)
  }[plan_type]
end
```

Currently if I pass in "bar" as the `plan_type`, every method will be run, how can I only run just the `plan_is_bar` method?

Comment: There are lots of ways to achieve the effect you seem to want (call a method depending on a named type or other logic). If you are going to call the method immediately, a Hash like this may not be the easiest way. However, it could be useful if you want to defer making the call until later on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what about this variant?

```
def method(plan_type, plan, user)
  {
    foo: -> { plan_is_foo(plan, user) },
    bar: -> { plan_is_bar(plan, user) },
    waa: -> { plan_is_waa(plan, user) },
    har: -> { plan_is_har(user) }
  }[plan_type].call
end
```

Using lambdas or procs is a good way to make things lazy, because they are executed only when they receive method `call`

Because of this you can use `->`(lambda literal) as lightweight wrapper around probably heavy calculations and `call` it only when you needed.

Comment: You could also explain a little about the lambdas and how they solve the OP's problem with his code making the all the possible method calls before returning the correct value. Most importantly, you have not made the values here into methods (which is not really possible in Ruby), but Procs containing the correct method calls (and these are also closures).

Comment: You have a small problem with `method`'s arguments, as `method(:har, "bob")` will raise an `ArgumentError` exception. I dealt with that by giving `plan` an arbitrary default value. Further to @Neil's point, you need only create (and then call) one lambda: `def method(plan_type, plan=nil, user); if plan_type == :har; ->(user) { plan_is_har(user) }.call user; else; case plan_type; when :foo then ->(plan,user) { plan_is_foo(plan, user) }; when :bar then ->(plan,user) { plan_is_bar(plan, user) }; when :waa then ->(plan,user) { plan_is_waa(plan, user) }; end.call plan, user; end; end`.

Answer (score 1):

A very straightforward solution:

**Code**

```
def method(plan_type, plan=nil, user)
  m =
  case plan_type
  when "foo" then :plan_is_foo
  when "bar" then :plan_is_bar
  when "waa" then :plan_is_waa
  when "har" then :plan_is_har
  else nil
  end

  raise ArgumentError, "No method #{plan_type}" if m.nil?
  (m==:plan_is_har) ? send(m, user) : send(m, plan, user)
end
```

You could of course use a hash instead of a `case` statement.

**Example**

```
def plan_is_foo plan, user
  "foo's idea is to #{plan} #{user}"
end

def plan_is_bar plan, user
  "bar's idea is to #{plan} #{user}"
end

def plan_is_waa plan, user
  "waa's idea is to #{plan} #{user}"
end

def plan_is_har user
  "har is besotted with #{user}"
end
```

```
method "foo", "marry", "Jane"
  #=> "foo's idea is to marry Jane"

method "bar", "avoid", "Trixi at all costs"
  #=> "bar's idea is to avoid Trixi at all costs" 

method "waa", "double-cross", "Billy-Bob"
  #=> "waa's idea is to double-cross Billy-Bob"

method "har", "Willamina"
  #=> "har is besotted with Willamina"

method "baz", "Huh?"
  #=> ArgumentError: No method baz
```